# Primefaces chart get selected value?

Tags: primefaces

Is there a way to retrieve the selected value from a primefaces chart?

According to the showcase [Interactive chart](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/interactive.xhtml) I can only get the series index and the item index.

if I have X axis "year" and Y "quantity", when clicked is there a way to get the "year" selected?
or in case of pie, get the selected label?